# Eigenvectors of a symmetric complex matrix matrix fail to form a complete basis

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, symmetric-matrices

I am required to diagonalize a particular symmetric complex matrix $M$ given by these [data](https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fo/7kijaucjoy3n8z38cd8ek/h?rlkey=xiuern890jutopwfd72a607a7&dl=0).

The matrix has distinct eigenvalues and orthogonal eigenvectors.

But the (normalized) eigenvectors do not seem to follow the completeness relation $\sum_i{\bf v}_i{\bf v}_i^T={\bf I}$.

As a test, I built a separate random symmetric complex matrix then diagonalized it. The completeness relation is satisfied in this case.

I really am puzzled and would appreciated any insight.

Thanks in advanced!

P/S: The link [data](https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fo/7kijaucjoy3n8z38cd8ek/h?rlkey=xiuern890jutopwfd72a607a7&dl=0) contains:

1. `M_Re.csv` which is the real part of $M$,
2. `M_Im.csv` which is the imaginary part of $M$,
3. `Diag.nb` which is the Mathematica codes for doing the computation (you don't have to use it if you prefer some other software).

Comment: If you have the correct eigenvectors and they are orthonormal then, other than numerical noise, the relationship will hold. So one of the first two conditions must not hold. Presumably you have checked the Gramian?

Comment: If it's complex number, you likely need to take the conjugate transpose (not the transpose).

Comment: You need to compute $\sum_k v_k v_k^*$, **not** what you have above.

Comment: Was curious, so I loaded the matrix into Octave. $M$ is essentially equal to its transpose, $\|M-M^T\| \approx 10^{-10}$, but it is not Hermitian $\|M-M^*\| > 10^5$. The eigenvectors are **not** orthogonal, I do not know why you made that assertion.

Comment: Hi @copper.hat. Thanks for checking it out. I think there is a misunderstanding here. The matrix $M$ is symmetric but not hermitian, as you pointed out. Indeed, a symmetric complex matrix that is hermitian is a real matrix, which is not what I am concerned with.

The goal is to diagonalize $M$ in the same way as one would diagonalize a real symmetric matrix. A similar proof as in the real case would show that eigenvectors corresponding to different eigenvalues are orthogonal with respect to the inner product $\langle a,b\rangle = a^Tb$.

Comment: That is not an inner product on the space of complex matrices. The matrix is not normal. The eigenvectors are linearly independent but not orthogonal.

Comment: Hi. I agree with your statement that the matrix is not normal. Although I disagree with the statement that eigenvectors are not orthogonal. Allow me to display the proof as follows.

Assume $u$ and $v$ are eigenvectors of a symmetric matrix $M$ corresponding to different eigenvalues $\lambda$ and $\mu$. We have $Mu=\lambda u$ and $Mv=\mu v$. Multipling the first equation with $v^T$ and the second with $u^T$ and take the difference, we get $v^TMu-u^TMv=\lambda v^Tu-\mu u^Tv=(\lambda-\mu)v^Tu$. Since $M^T=M$, the l.h.s of this equation vanishes and orthogonality follows.